# The basics of a ENV file

Tags: node.js, discord.js, dotenv

I’m using a hosting website to host my discord bot and my .env stores the token. How does it still work when the file is .gitignored? Because I don’t want people stealing my token and using it for other purposes.

Comment: can you post your git ignore file?

Comment: "*How does it still work when the file is .gitignored*" have you checked in the file and then added it to .gitignore? If you've done that, then the file is still present in the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial deployment process on your hosting needs to be more complex than "Pull the application from my Git repository".

For simple applications that generally just means you create the `.env` file on the hosting manually.

For complex systems (e.g. when you have multiple instances of the application on different servers) you'll generate it from a secure data store as part of a process that involves a deployment tool like Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

You use gitignore and add the `.env` extension in it to make sure that it does not get pushed to the remote repository on github so that no-one can access those variables. in order to add the .env variables on a hosting website, you need to add the environment variables externally on that hosting site. The method depends entirely on the service provider.